# listing upcoming events in order by date

Tags: php, drupal

I currently list the upcoming events with the following code.

But it lists events in the wrong date order. I want to list the soonest upcoming event listed on the top and continue downwards with the same logic.
For example, if there are events this month on 17, 25, 27, 28.

I want to list;
event on 25th
event on 27th
event on 28th

```
<?php $get_latest_events = get_latest_events(5);

    if(count($get_latest_events) > 0) {
      foreach($get_latest_events as $eventdata) {
        $entity_data = node_load($eventdata->entity_id);
        $event_start_date = check_isset_start_date($entity_data,'event_calendar_date','und');
            if($event_start_date !='') {
             $explode_event_date = explode(" ",$event_start_date);
             $explode_event_day = strtotime($explode_event_date[0]);
             $explode_event_time = $explode_event_date[1];

             $event_start_day1 = strftime("%B",$explode_event_day);
             $event_start_day2 = strftime("%d",$explode_event_day);

            }
        $location = check_isset($entity_data,'field_location','und');

      ?>

                <li class="clearfix">                                       
                </li>

    <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Use ORDER BY DESC command when you are making query from your database.

Comment: @Efe can you provide an example of the data returned by get_latest_events() ?